# On reconcile, set style.top to 0

Tags: reactjs

I have an array of 3 elements, I created a sortable. When the user `mousedown`'s, I set the style.top of the element as they `mousemove`. Now on `mouseup` in the first image below I do not do set state, therefore this is NO reconciliation.

In the second image, I do set state on `mouseup`, so there IS reconciliation. I want the reconciliation, but when it does reconcile I need to set the `style.top` to `0`, otherwise things are out of order, as seen in the second image below.

Is there anyway to set the `style.top` on reconcile?

First image - no set state, so reconciliation doesn't happen. This is the final visual I want to acheive, but I need reconciliation:

[image]

Second image - with state, so reconciliation happens. But I want to set `style.top` to `0` if it reconciles, is this possible? If I don't set the top to 0, on set state, it is out of order due to reconciliation, as seen in this image below. The final visual should match the first image above.

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Show us some code. At least the render method of your component.

Comment: Take a look at the [`componentWillReceiveProps `](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#updating-componentwillreceiveprops) and [`componentDidUpdate`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#updating-componentdidupdate) lifecycle methods. Those should be what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks all! I'll check that out, here is my code though @Atanas - https://github.com/Noitidart/Profilist/blob/master/resources/scripts/cp.js#L415-L630 I didn't share it because its quite a bit of code.

Comment: Thanks @MatthewHerbst I'll check those out, is there an argument to those functions or something that will let me know its being reconciled? :)

Comment: Read through the docs I linked to. You will see that certain life cycle methods are only called if there is reconciliation